# SharePoint: Need Help with calculated/Lookup fields:

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Need Help with calculated fields:

Activity_List : ActivityID, ActivityName, ActivityPerson  (This list is used as template to prefill the projectList columns. i.e)

ProjectList: ProjectID, ActivityID, ActivityName, ActivityPerson.
As soon as you select ActivityID, it prefills the ActivityName and ActivityPerson.

How do i do this is in SharePoint List

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are no standard or widely confirmed way to do that. 
However, there also also some suggestions which may enlighten you a bit! 
No.1 Building a custom field type to create a field based on parent child relation 
for any custom list. This link http://blog.12thwave.com/?p=7 may help you to 
do this.

Another building Solution is [Cascaded Lookup](http://www.boostsolutions.com/cascaded-lookup.html). To deal with abundant of data, this solution is worthwhile to consider!

Cheers